# Should I move the class to the end of the file by using the forward declaration?

Tags: c++

In one file, I can write the following two codes, which one is better for other maintainers?

First (top-down feeling):

```
Class B;
Class A {
  B *b;
};
Class B {
};
```

Second (bottom-up feeling):

```
Class B {
};
Class A {
  B *b;
};
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, use whatever looks nicer to you..

Comment: I don't think questions about trivial aspects/preferences of coding style are useful. Also, that code wouldn't compile, as you forgot the trailing semicolons after the class definitions.

Comment: One thing that _could_ make a difference depending on your design of classes - by using forward declarations, you can only use pointers, or references to such a class.

Comment: typical use case of forward declarations is to resolve mutual dependency. Mutual dependency isnt nice, so I would avoid forward declarations when there is no need for it, because it looks like there is mutual dependency when actually there is none. Anyhow, once you specify what you actually mean with "better" you would realize that there is no difference other than subjective reasons. Voting to close as opinion based

Comment: It looks like bottom-up just because they are named `B` and `A`. If it had been `stream_buffer` and `stream` it would have looked just right.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using forward declarations. They only help the compiler, most programmers just ignore them when reading code. In your second option, if you B class ever uses A, you will still need to use declarations. I would go with the first option if I were you.

Comment: And if you ever decide that rather than have `B* b` you want `B b`, then you end up having to swap them - refactoring is just something people have to do because if you could predict the future perfectly then you'd get it right first time every time.